# JavaFX Combobox doesn't change to clicked value from the first and second click

Tags: java, javafx, combobox

I have a `ComboBox` named `verreGcombo` that gets populated with items of type `Verre`, the problem I face is that when I want to select a value from it, it always fail to change its value on the first and the second click and sometimes more, so I always have to use arrows to navigate and select items or click more than three times to select an item. this issue isn't present with other ComboBoxes ( which items number doesn't exceed 5), here is my code :

```
List<Verre> ListeVerres = em.createQuery("SELECT v FROM Verre v").getResultList();
        ObservableList<Verre> dataVerres = FXCollections.observableList(ListeVerres);
        ListeVerres.add(null);

        verreGcombo.setCellFactory((comboBox) -> {
            return new ListCell<Verre>() {
                @Override
                protected void updateItem(Verre item, boolean empty) {
                    super.updateItem(item, empty);

                    if (item == null || empty) {
                        setText("Choisir");
                        verreGcombo.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();
                        //verreGcombo.getItems().clear();
                    } else {
                        setText(item.getMatiere() + " " + item.getType());
                    }
                }
            };
        });

// Define rendering of selected value shown in ComboBox.
        verreGcombo.setConverter(new StringConverter<Verre>() {
            @Override
            public String toString(Verre verre) {
                if (verre == null) {
                    return "Choisir";
                } else {
                    return verre.getMatiere() + " " + verre.getType();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public Verre fromString(String articleString) {
                return null; // No conversion fromString needed.
            }
        });

        verreGcombo.setOnAction((e) -> {

            Verre verreG = verreGcombo.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();

            if (verreG != null) {

                verreGprixT.setText(setFloat(verreG.getArticle().getPrixVenteTTC()));
                verreGPrixHR = verreG.getArticle().getPrixVenteTTC();
                verreGRemise = (verreGPrixHR * verreG.getArticle().getRemise()) / 100;
                verreGPrix = verreGPrixHR - verreGRemise;
                indice.setText(setFloat(verreG.getIndice()));
                verreGfield.setText(verreG.getMatiere() + " " + verreG.getType());

            } else {
                verreGprixT.setText(setFloat(0));
                verreGPrixHR = 0;
                verreGRemise = 0;
                verreGPrix = 0;
                indice.setText(setFloat(0));
                verreGfield.setText("");

            }
        });

        verreGcombo.setItems(dataVerres);
```

Answer (score 0):

You Have to Add an EventFilter to you Comboboxs and listen to mouse clicks so you can change the value whenever the user clicks on an item using mouse. Here is the code you have to Add to fix the problem.

```
verreGcombo.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
    public void handle(MouseEvent e) {
        Verre verreG = verreGcombo.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();

           if (verreG != null) {

                verreGprixT.setText(setFloat(verreG.getArticle().getPrixVenteTTC()));
                verreGPrixHR = verreG.getArticle().getPrixVenteTTC();
                verreGRemise = (verreGPrixHR * verreG.getArticle().getRemise()) / 100;
                verreGPrix = verreGPrixHR - verreGRemise;
                indice.setText(setFloat(verreG.getIndice()));
                verreGfield.setText(verreG.getMatiere() + " " + verreG.getType());

            } else {
                verreGprixT.setText(setFloat(0));
                verreGPrixHR = 0;
                verreGRemise = 0;
                verreGPrix = 0;
                indice.setText(setFloat(0));
                verreGfield.setText("");
        }
    };
});
```

I hope this Code solve your Problem.

Comment: It did actually solve it, but I don't know why the other comboboxes work without a MouseEvent Handler, I think it has something to do with the length of the items list